# Separating comma-separated text using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

How do I separate comma-separated text using PyQGIS?

I have coordinates in text.
For example, text 42.800392, 24.229796. I want to store 42.800392 and 24.229796 in each variable.

I think we can use the 'split' function, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: How does your text looks like? In which format is it? What output do you expect to have? If it is a string record try this `'42.800392, 24.229796'.split(', ')`

Comment: https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-access-vector-layer-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the coordinates from text you could use a python regex:

```
text = "latitude: 42.800392, longitude: 24.229796"
coordinates = re.findall('\d*\.?\d+',text)
coordinates[0] 
coordinates[1]
```